# Record Live Stream http to a file using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, video, stream, record, live

I have a live stream URL http and I want to record live video for some periods of time.
How can I do this for Xamarin Android code ? 
thank you

Comment: "live stream" could mean a million different things

Comment: I have a tv live video link http://..../505.ts , I can play it using vlc or other , but I want to record it to a file .mp4 during some period of time. How can I achieve this using Xamarin or .Net C#?